# Hello, I am trying to web scrape a website to get their daily deals but running into errors with find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a website (new Egg) for daily deals but I am encountering an issue with the find_all parameter.

```
#imported Modules and Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


#Website to be scraped
website = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/DailyDeal?icid=368517')
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')


#Getting container with all featured items
all_deals = soup.find(class_='items-view.is-grid')

#Featured Items in container
item = all_deals.find_all(class_= 'item-container')

#putting values in a list
product_title = [item.find(class_= 'item-title').text()for item in item]
maker = [item.find(class_='item-brand').text()for item in item]
price_before = [item.find(class_= 'price-was').text()for item in item]
price_now = [item.find(class_= 'price-current').text()for item in item]
price_saved = [item.find(class_= 'price-save').text()for item in item]
shipping = [item.find(class_= 'price-ship').text()for item in item]
product_link = [item.find('a',['href']) for item in item]

Deals_of_the_day = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'item-title': product_title,
    'item-brand': maker,
    'price-was': price_before,
    'price-current': price_now,
    'price-save': price_saved,
    'price-ship': shipping,
   # 'a',['href']: product_link,
     })

print(Deals_of_the_day)
Deals_of_the_day.to_csv('New_Egg_Daily_Deals.csv')
```

I expect them to be in a csv file.

```
Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/elise/PycharmProjectsPython Boring Projects/Web Scraping New_Egg Website .py", line 16, in <module>
    item = all_deals.find_all(class_= 'item-container')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: `soup.find(class_='items-view.is-grid')` isn't finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match multiple classes with `soup.find()`; the `class_` argument is treated as a single class to search for. Use `soup.select()` instead:

```
all_deals = soup.select(".items-view.is-grid")
```

You can combine this with the `.item-container` class:

```
item = soup.select(".items-view.is-group .item-container")
```

Comment: How do I extract an image from the brand class, since the text is not available?

Comment: `soup.select(".item-brand img")` will find all the images. Then you can get the `title` and `src` attributes from them.

Comment: Do you mind shooting me an email at (yeahtweets@gmail.com) I have some troubling questions to ask?

Comment: Sorry, I don't provide private consulting, I just answer here in public.

Comment: Here is the link to all the code: https://github.com/elisee10/Web-Scraping-Project-2/tree/master |                                                                   
 The error message is:   line 41
    Deals_of_the_day.to_csv('New_Egg_Deals.csv') Invalid syntax
                   ^

Comment: You have line 38 commented out. It contains the closing brace and parentheses for `Deals_of_the_day = pd.DataFrame(`

Comment: Error: This is the error i am getting, do i need a module for image?
 line 19, in <module> maker = [soup.select(".item-brand img").get_img()for item in items]
 py", line 19, in <listcomp> | maker [soup.select(".item-brand img").get_img()for item in items]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_img'

Comment: Also, do you mind telling me what I can improve on my code or change?

Comment: There's no `get_img()` method in Beautiful Soup, where did you get that from? What is it supposed to do? If you want to get the title, it would be `[img['title'] for img in soup.select(".item-brand img")]`

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got that fixed, but my results are not printing out every appropriate value. It is more like ;                                                 item-title  ...                          price-ship
0   CORSAIR RMx Series RM1000X 1000W 80 PLUS GOLD ...  ...   \r\n        Free Shipping\r\n    and leaving the model, image, price saved, etc

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but you seem to be getting further from the original question.

Comment: Not sure how you're relating the images returned by `soup.select(".item-brand img")` with the deals in `all_deals`.